# How to add bash variable to json file?

Tags: json, bash

I have a `daemon.json` file which contains one line as below

```
{ "insecure-registries":["192.X.X.X:8123"] }
```

I am trying to use a variable to change generically to the current IP address. In bash script normally
I'd store in a variable like

```
  myip=hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'
 { "insecure-registries":["$myip:8123"] }
```

How to use a kind of variable in JSON file?

Comment: `jq -cn --arg myip "$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')" '{ "insecure-registries":["\($myip):8123"] }'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to `jq`, I would recommend storing not JSON, but a `jq` filter, like

```
{"insecure-registries": ["\($ip):8123"]}
```

Assume the preceding is in file named `foo.jq`; then using `jq` as follows to *produce* JSON from the filter.

```
$ myip=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')  # 192.0.2.42, e.g.
$ jq -nf foo.jq --arg ip "$myip"
{
  "insecure-registries": [
    "192.0.2.42:8123"
  ]
}
```

JSON itself doesn't have a notion of substitution, and `bash` itself isn't really suitable for making substitutions like this.

Comment: Huh. Did you reopen this, or am I mistaken in thinking I'd closed the question as a duplicate? (I don't see any edit history to confirm).

Comment: I did reopen; I was half-way through typing this up when you closed it :) I think the duplicate did not quite capture what the OP is looking to do.

Comment: Huh. I *do* still consider it duplicative of numerous other "how do I generate JSON from bash?" questions, but... que será, será.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i've checked the Qs you mentioned but is not really the same. I really try to avoid duplication always

Comment: @chepner I don't have access to `jq` :/

Comment: @full_steak_developer, if you don't have access to jq, we have several available duplicates that discuss using Python for the same purpose.

Comment: As far as i understood  it does not solve my issue.  File has to be with json extension.